# Is ithere a WCF plugin for Glimpse?

Tags: wcf, glimpse

We have a Silverlight application that communicates with the back end via WCF. Is it possible to use Glimpse to monitor those calls like it does for AJAX calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An answer from one of the Glimpse developers, Anthony van der Hoorn ([avanderhoorn](https://github.com/avanderhoorn)), on one of the issues in GitHub states the following in regard to using Glimpse with WCF.

> We don't have any immediate plans for WCF, but if someone in the
>   community wanted to start work on it, we would certainly love to help
>   support that effort.
>
> https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/337#issuecomment-19885545

So unfortunately the answer is **No**, *not yet*.

Comment: Thanks Ben, thought that was the case, nice to have it confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a WCF plugin for Glimpse: https://github.com/stweb/Glimpse.WCF

Comment: awesome! Do you know if it adds any overhead? Is there a way to turn it on/off?

Comment: ...and Thank You for going to the effort!

Comment: I'm lost on how to add the component to my app.  I know I add a reference, but how do i register it?  Do i add it to my WCF app/host or to the web site code?  Last question, will this allow insight into the EF6 code running in my WCF services?

Comment: The page mentions nuget, but I can't find it. Is it available on nuget?